# The HTTP request is unauthorized... Error

Tags: wcf, wsdl

Im administering several iis 10 on servers 2016

a developer is performing a POST to the WCF service hosted on IIS on one of the iis servers

he is getting the below error.

when I'm performing a simple request (pasting the url in IE) using IE browser, Im successfully getting the application's wsdl page

iis authentication is set to anonymous, windows authentication(1.negotiate, 2.NTLM)

when I remove anonymous auth, I'm getting a prompt for credentials when trying to reach the url from IE.

[image: IIS Authentication]

> setspn -l SERVER00

Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=SERVER00,OU=Corporate Policy,OU=Prod Servers,OU=Servers,DC=domain,DC=com
WSMAN/SERVER00.domain.com
WSMAN/SERVER00
TERMSRV/SERVER00
TERMSRV/SERVER00.domain.com
RestrictedKrbHost/SERVER00
HOST/SERVER00
RestrictedKrbHost/SERVER00.domain.com
HOST/SERVER00.domain.com

**Error message:**

*System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate oW0wa6ADCgEBomQEYmBgBgkqhkiG9xIBAgIDAH5RME+gAwIBBaEDAgEepBEYDzIwMjEwMjA3MDg1NjQ3WqUFAgMJ/eSmAwIBKakMGwpBSUcuTkVULklMqhYwFKADAgEBoQ0wCxsJc3ZjcHdzaW5m'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The target principal name is incorrect...*

Help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you use windows authentication, the client needs to provide windows credentials when calling the server:

```
Service1Client service1Client = new Service1Client();
 service1Client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "Administrator";
 service1Client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "Password";
```

If the client does not provide windows credentials, an error will be reported:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ding Peng. could you elaborate on how I can recreate this check ? is this a screenshot of the code in backend? is there a way to validate what you are suggesting?

Comment: I call the WCF service through the proxy class. How do you call the WCF service?

Comment: so I can use postman. the developer has his own inhouse developed application which I dont have access to.

Comment: I suggest you generate proxy classes to call WCF services based on the WSDL file of the WCF service. Postman can only be used for testing under certain circumstances.